# PHP concatenate variable with constant

Tags: php, static, constants

I have a static `View` class that gets passed a string from another class. When the string is passed through as a variable it works. When I change it to a constant the error is:

> [17-Feb-2016 19:08:48 Europe/Berlin] PHP Warning:  include(): Failed
>   opening
>   '/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/its_vegan/scripts/back_end/views/template'
>   for inclusion
>   (include_path='.:/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.0.0/lib/php') in
>   /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/its_vegan/scripts/back_end/views/view.php on
>   line 23

```
class View {

    /**
     * -------------------------------------
     * Render a Template.
     * -------------------------------------
     * 
     * @param $filePath - include path to the template.
     * @param null $viewData - any data to be used within the template.
     * @return string - 
     * 
     */
    public static function render( $filePath, $viewData = null ) {

        // Was any data sent through?
        ( $viewData ) ? extract( $viewData ) : null;

        ob_start();
        include ( $filePath );// error on this line
        $template = ob_get_contents();
        ob_end_clean();

        return $template;
    }
}

class CountrySelect {

    const template = 'select_template.php'; //the const is template

    public static function display() {

        if ( class_exists( 'View' ) ) {

            // Get the full path to the template file.

            $templatePath = dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/' . template; //the const is template

            $viewData = array(
                "options" => '_countries',
                "optionsText" => 'name',
                "optionsValue" => 'geonameId',
                "value" => 'selectedCountry',
                "caption" => 'Country'
            );

            // Return the rendered HTML
            return View::render( $templatePath, $viewData );

        }
        else {
            return "You are trying to render a template, but we can't find the View Class";
        }
    }
}
```

What did work was having this in the CountrySelect:

```
$templatePath = dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/' . static::$template;
```

Why does the template have to be static? Can I make it a static constant?

Comment: You need to refer to it using `self::constname`

Comment: Access to class constants done via the double-colon `::` operator.  (AKA Scope Resolution Operator).  If the `static` keyword is bothering you then an alternative is `self`.  The [docs can shed some light](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.late-static-bindings.php) on the topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At this line

```
$templatePath = dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/' . template;
```

`template` is not constant, because constant `template` declared inside class. This code works similar

```
$templatePath = dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/template';
```

so, use `static::template`

Comment: Not my downvote, but OP's code shows as `const template = 'select_template.php'; //the const is template` and seems out of scope.

Comment: whoever downvoted, should now retract. It'd be the honorable thing to do.

Answer (score 4):

You could also use `self::template`
Since class constants are defined at a per class level instead of per-object, `static::template` will refer to the same, unless you have a child class. (See https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.late-static-bindings.php)

`template` refers to a global constant (e.g. by `define('template', 'value');`)